# Proving whether a series is stationary

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity

I want to prove whether the following equation is stationary or not:

$$
x_t = (x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) (1+k(x_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t})^2)^{-1/2}
$$
Also written like:
$$
x_t = (x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k(x_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t})^2}} 
$$

where $k$ is a constant: $0<k<1$, and $ \epsilon_{t} $ is a random walk:
$$
\epsilon_{t}=\epsilon_{t-1}+\omega_t
$$
and $\omega_t$ is $iid(\mu=0,\sigma^2)$. The second part of the main equation is actually always less than 1.

I tried deriving the variance but this was getting unwieldy and was unsure I would be able to answer the question with it. I also tried converting it to a geometric series in the hopes I could prove its convergence but I couldn't get past dealing with a "changing" ratio. I would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Some context:

The equation is actually a simplified version of a physical storage model. What I really want to know is whether non-stationary errors on the store ($x_t$) will show up properly (as non-stationarity) in simulations. In other words, does the model effectively "remove" the non-stationarity property.

Simulation results:

Because $x_t$ represents physical storage it shouldn't really be allowed to be negative which seems to be crucial but I may worry about that later on.

For the following inputs:
$$
k=1/100, \mu=0, \sigma^2=1
$$
I get these typical plots when $\epsilon_t$ drifts into the negative:
[image]

When $\epsilon_t$ drifts into the positive:
[image]

The model tends towards two different points, so does this imply that $x_t$ is non-stationary? The question that is important to me is: is there a way to prove this without simulations?

On the advice of whuber, I also computed the $\tan(\pi x_t/2)$ shown below:
[image]

Comment: There are three regimes: $0\lt k\lt 1,$ $k=1,$ and $k \gt 1.$  I find it helpful to study $\tan(\pi x_t/2).$  The case $k=1$ clearly is not stationary; the others look trickier to characterize.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your advice. I'm sorry could you please give me a bit more of a clue RE the tan function. Do you mean that I should apply it to both sides and work with that? Also, my intuition must be off but I don't see how the k=1 case is not stationary.

Comment: One way to acquire intuition is through simulation.  When you do that, you will discover that eventually $x_t$ tends to be very close to $1$ or very close to $0$ for long intervals, making it difficult to perceive what is happening.  By tracking instead the series $y_t=\tan(\pi x_t/2)$ you will become able to detect how the distribution of $y_t$ changes as $t$ grows. Such changes will suggest whether a limiting or stable form of the distribution is even possible.

Comment: @whuber thanks again for your reply. I updated the post to include some simulation results as per your suggestion. I'm wondering about how I should interpret $y_t=\tan(\pi x_t/2)$. As $t$ increases, $y_t$ seems to converge to 0. Does this imply $y_t$ is stationary and so $x_t$ is also stationary?

Comment: What you want to explore is how the *full distribution* of $x_t$ (or $\tan x_t$) changes with $t.$  To do that, you need to generate many independent trajectories, summarize them by $t$ (with descriptive statistics or--preferably--graphically), and explore how those summaries change with $t.$  Examining just a single trajectory unfortunately does not supply much insight.